# postgreSQL password authentication failed for user

Tags: windows-10, pgadmin-4, postgresql-14

I'm taking a full WebDev course and got really hard stuck on this matter. I've installed postgreSQL 14.2 for Windows 10 and the instructor said that pgAdmin4 would come together, which it didn't, so then i installed pgAdmin4 individually. I've setted everything up and created a testing database, which is called *'test'*, and also a table, everything through Windows Powershell command lines, following the course instructions. Now, when i try to access this database through PowerShell command `psql 'test'` and type the requested password for the OS user i get a Fatal Error, which follows:

```
PS C:\Users\theu_\desktop> psql 'test'
Password for user theu_:
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "theu_"
```

I've tried my OS username password and the postgreSQL password, none of them works. What am i missing or did wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try accessing postgres by using `psql -U postgres` in cmd, postgres being the name of the superuser for postgres itself (if you did a basic install) - while windows is probably trying to access postgres with your windows name.

You should also be able to use SQL Shell to access your database without denoting a user.